# send changed hashmap but get the same one using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, hashmap, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2345);

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    Map<Integer, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    testMap.put(1,1);
    oos.writeObject(testMap);
    oos.flush();

    testMap.put(2,2);
    oos.writeObject(testMap);
    oos.flush();

    oos.close();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2345);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    System.out.println((HashMap<Integer, Integer>) ois.readObject());
    System.out.println((HashMap<Integer, Integer>) ois.readObject());

    ois.close;
}
```

The code above is from two files.
When running them, the console prints the same result:

```
{1=1}
{1=1}
```

How can this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ObjectOutputStream remembers the objects it has written already and on repeated writes will only output a pointer (and not the contents again). This preserves object identity and is necessary for cyclic graphs.

So what your stream contains is basically:

- HashMap A with contents {1:1}
- pointer: "HashMap A again"

You need to use a fresh HashMap instance in your case.

Comment: You can also reset the ObjectOutputStream (rather than having to create a new hashmap object).

Comment: thank you, and i am wondering whether this happens on other data structures?

Comment: Sure, this happens with all objects.

Answer (score 2):

As [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10809442/758280) already said, an `ObjectOutputStream` keeps a cache of things it has written already. You can either use a fresh map as he suggests, or clear the cache.

Calling [`ObjectOutputStream.reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) between the calls to `writeObject` will clear the cache and give you the behavior you originally expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> foo = new HashMap<>();
        foo.put(1, 1);
        oos.writeObject(foo);
        // oos.reset();
        foo.put(2, 2);
        oos.writeObject(foo);
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais)) {
        System.out.println(ois.readObject());
        System.out.println(ois.readObject());
    }
}
```